# Eliminate same string

Tags: vb.net

I have input file all_words.txt

In files i have list of some words, for example:

```
JIM IS JANITOR
BALL IS FOR BASKETBALL
JIM IS LAWYER
CAIRO IS MAIN CAPITAL OF EGYPT
```

etc...

I need to find only one string and eliminate others for example `JIM (tab) IS JANITOR`, i can split with tab, but im finding all strings. I tried with dictionary but i think it's not good solution.

Do you have any better solution?

The correct output is:

```
JIM IS JANITOR
BALL IS FOR BASKETBALL
CAIRO IS MAIN CAPITAL OF EGYPT
```

My code:

```
Dim all_words As String() = File.ReadAllLines("all_words.txt")
Dim allWordsDict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For Each awd As String In all_words
    Try
        allWordsDict.Add(awd.ToUpper(), awd.Split(vbTab).FirstOrDefault().ToUpperInvariant())
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine(awd)
    Console.ReadLine()
Next
```

Comment: What is `so.ToUpper()` in your code? Where is `so` defined?

Comment: Sorry, i edited. Now is correct, it must be awd.

Comment: Don't use `Option Strict Off`. Your code should not even compile. At least one thing doesn't work if it was `Strict On`: `awd.Split(vbTab)`. Because Split has no overload which takes only a string. This doesn't cause your issue because this string is only one char, but in other code that might cause a very ugly bug. `Strict Off` will take the first char of the string and use that for `String.Split`. So for example: `"Foo_+_Bah".Split("_+_")` will compile with `Off` but will give the wrong result.

Comment: Yes i tried and didnt work...

Comment: What is your condition for leaving 'JIM IS LAWYER' out? Is it because the first word was already found as a first word elsewhere?

Comment: I need only one word, so if i have 3 word jim is something, i will use only one. It could be first, second, etc.. It's not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a LINQ "Group By" clause to group lines by the first word, and then take the first item in each grouping:

```
Dim result = (
    From line In File.ReadLines("all_words.txt")
    Group By line.Split(" "c).First() Into g = Group ' assuming spaces for word separator
    Select g.First()
)

For Each line In result
    Console.WriteLine(line)
Next
```

Result:

```
JIM IS JANITOR
BALL IS FOR BASKETBALL
CAIRO IS MAIN CAPITAL OF EGYPT
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding to the dictionary you are not using the correct key

```
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        dim s as string = "JIM" + Chr(9) + "IS JANITOR" + chr(13) + 
        "BALL" + Chr(9) + "IS FOR BASKETBALL" + chr(13) + 
        "JIM" + Chr(9) + "IS LAWYER" + chr(13) + 
        "CAIRO" + Chr(9) + "IS MAIN CAPITAL OF EGYPT"

        Dim all_words As String() = s.Split(chr(13))
        Dim allWordsDict As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        For Each awd As String In all_words
            Try
                dim dictionaryWords as String() = awd.Split(vbtab)
                allWordsDict.Add(dictionaryWords(0), awd)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next

        'Looping dictionary
        for each entry in allWordsDict
            Console.WriteLine(entry.Value)
        next
    End Sub
End Module
```

**Output:**

```
JIM    IS JANITOR
BALL    IS FOR BASKETBALL
CAIRO    IS MAIN CAPITAL OF EGYPT
```